# How to convert android module to java module in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-module

I have created three modules for my android app namely app, domain, and data.

By mistake, I have created domain and data modules as android module instead of Java module. Now I want to replace them to Java modules.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to change:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

and add the following line after it:

```
sourceCompatibility= 1.7
targetCompatibility= 1.7
```

in your build.gradle android library module.